# How will i get the selected year records using QueryDatabaseTable?

Tags: apache-nifi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymNXO.jpg)I want to get the specific year records using QueryDatabaseTable processor, How can I achieve, if I am using select * from table where year > 2018 in querydatabasetable it is not working. Please help

Comment: Please provide the configuration of your `QueryDatabaseTable` processor and the results you are getting (an error stacktrace, no flowfiles, etc.) Also include a segment of your existing table showing there are matching records and demonstrate that the same query run in a different environment (CLI, query editor) returns expected results.

Comment: @Andy Image attached in the question..  and that is my QueryDatabaseTable configuration. the same query will working fine in my source database. please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom query, instead of using the `Table Name` and `Columns To Return` properties, it will take the custom query and wrap it by aliasing the result set of your custom query to `Table Name`. So the SELECT part of the generated SQL in your case will look like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from table where year > 2018) test
```

Does that query work in your source database? Are you sure you want the `table` table rather than the `test` table in your custom query? If you meant `test`, then your custom query is only adding a `WHERE` clause, consider using the `Additional WHERE clause` property rather than the `Custom Query` property.

If none of these suggestions work, please update your question as Andy suggested, to include any errors/stacktraces in the logs and/or the behavior of any flow files coming out of QueryDatabaseTable.

Comment: @mattb The table name itself test, But I mentioned as table instead of test for better understanding, and yes the query is working as test table